# Move data from one table to other in mysql and drop the table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to write a Mysql query for the following scenario.

1.check if a table( ex: tableA) exists.

2.Check if data is there in the table.

3.If tableA exists and data is there in the table move all data to another table( ex: tableB) (tableB there in db and both tables are having same structure)

4.drop tableA

Is it possible to write a mysql query avoiding mysql stored procedure ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do first three with the below query, but drop table was not possible.
Hope it helps!

There are two tables: table_1(old),table_2(new). Both have one column "ID".

```
insert into table_2(id)     #inserts into table
select case when
(
select count(*) from table_1 a       #checks if there are any records in the table
where exists                            #checks if table exists
(select 1 from table_1 b where a.id=b.id))>0 then
id
else 0 end
from table_1
```